# Items in list are also lists and I want to make them strings - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a function that takes in a list with values that are strings. It returns just the names of locations in the original list of words. The problem is somewhere in this function it makes each individual item a list itself. I'm thinking it happens when GeoText is used, but I can't figure out a fix.

Function:

```
    def extractLocs(self) :
        data = self
        locations = []
        locs = []
        for item in data :
            locations.append(GeoText(item))
        for i in locations :
            locs.append(i.countries)
            locs.append(i.cities)
        return locs
```

Output sample:

```
[['March'], ['Iran'], ['Palestine'], ['March'], ['Seattle'], ['Washington']]
```

Comment: `return [', '.join(locations) for locations in locs]`? Think about why that function returns a list. It is likely to sometimes have more than 1 element.

Comment: what about `locs.extend(i.countries)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a *list of lists* into **a single list** as follows. So, if you would like you could replace `vals` by `locs` in the following piece of code and that should address the problem.

***Note***: The following method would work no matter how many elements you have inside each *child-list*, or if a certain item is just an item and not a list.

```py
vals = [['March'], ['Iran'], ['Palestine'], ['March'], ['Seattle'], ['Washington']]

values = list()
for val in vals: values.extend(val) if isinstance(val, list) else values.append(val)
values
```

**Output**:

```
['March', 'Iran', 'Palestine', 'March', 'Seattle', 'Washington']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return([i[0] for i in locs])
```

or with `numpy`:

```
return(numpy.array(locs)[:,0])
```